# I can't download Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop

Tags: downloads

I have windows 8 on my PC and i really wanted to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop so i downloaded it from the official Ubuntu website ( www.ubuntu.com ) and I have  problem:

The file is 1020 mb large and after downloading 203mb, download is automatically finished. I tried more than 5 times but every time i face same problem.

Comment: You have internet connection problems. You can try to download using torrent.

Comment: Use a download manager which can resume download after interruption

Answer (score 0):

As the .iso file contains the whole OS, it is pretty big. It's recommended that you use a Download Manager, specially if your connection to the Internet is unstable.

A good way to download it quickly (And help canonical save some bandwith) is to use a BitTorrent client.
One of the most popular is µTorrent, here's a link to the win version:
 http://www.utorrent.com/intl/en/downloads/win
And here's a link to the Ubuntu alternative downloads (Scroll down to see the BitTorrent Links):
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

(Remember to leave the client open after you download the .iso, to help seed the file to your fellow users.)

If you prefer to download it through your Internet browser, there's a few great download manager extensions for both Firefox or Chrome (Just search them up!).